# whitespace not going away

Tags: html, css, image

I don't know how to get rid of random lines behind my pictures. My website is http://spencedesign.netau.net/singapore-gallery.html and you can see that there are little lines behind the images, and I can't see what is causing them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from here:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
  color: -webkit-link;
  text-decoration: underline; // this line is the problem
  cursor: auto;
}
```

Try to do something like:

```
.gallerycontainer a {
 text-decoration: none;
  }
```

This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your links, because they have more than just one `<img>` tag, are being underlined. Just add

```
a.thumbnail {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

to your css.

Answer (score 1):

Those are whitespaces, they are underlined because they are in an `<a>` tag, you can remove the whitespace or remove text-decoration from your `<a>`